# Как обеспечить HTTPS на flask python?

Tags: python, flask, ssl, https, tls

Как обеспечить https соединение на web фреймворке flask (python3)? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https соединение кого с кем где в какую сторону?

Comment: @andreymal Flask – это фреймворк для разработки серверов, очевидно, что вопрос про поддержку HTTPS на стороне сервера `:)`

Comment: @AivanF. а вдруг автор хочет из обработчика запроса отправить https-запрос на другой сервер :)

Comment: Я спрашивал про серверную сторону, ответ AvianF. помог, спасибо.

Comment: @PositronNN поставьте его ответу галочку в таком случае

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например так:

```py
from flask import Flask

from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.use_privatekey_file('server.key')
context.use_certificate_file('server.crt')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':  
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

Но это не очень хорошая практика, обрабатывать HTTPS внутри веб-приложения. Для этого обычно применяются прокси-сервера вроде [NginX](https://nginx.org/ru/), примеров его настройки полно, в т.ч на оф.сайте.

Где взять SSL/TLS сертификат это отдельный вопрос со своими нюансами – статей много (особенно на англ), погуглите. Вкратце: можно купить, можно сгенерировать простенький самому или на сайтах вроде [SSLforFree](https://www.sslforfree.com).

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'OpenSSL.SSL' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'`

Comment: @PositronNN ну-с, значит, Вашей версии библиотеки не поддерживается этот протокол `(:` Можете использовать [любой другой параметр](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT), например `PROTOCOL_TLS` – для использования максимальной доступной клиенту и серверу версии.

Comment: а если на windows машина какой прокси можно поставить?
Я могу использовать аналог lets encrypt?

Comment: @RustaDolokhov Let's Encrypt это не прокси, а сервис, который выдаёт SSL/TLS сертификаты, а поставить его на сервер, в т.ч прокси можно, любой. Если вы используете Windows Server, то наверное надо в Internet Information Services (IIS) всё настраивать. Во всяком случае, это совершенно отдельный вопрос, и по теме Винды я не особо разбираюсь.

Comment: Помогло создать контекст через `context = ('server.crt', 'server.key')`